# Generate VCF file through QR Code using flutter?

Tags: flutter, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I would like to share a user contact when another user scan his own qr code.

Scenario:

A user want to share his contact
Another user scan his QR Code
The final user has a VCF File to store locally information

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this in my flutter application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kashikha.qrprofile.
What I did is ask user to input their details, create vCard using vcf_maintained (https://pub.dev/packages/vcard_maintained) package and pass that vcard to qr_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter).
That will generate a QR Code when scanned in IOS camera, will open contact details of that person in contacts app. But in android we need to convert scanned QR data(String) to vcf back and open contact with that details.

Comment: can you please give an example code on how did you get the vcf_maintained worked with you? Because I'm getting an error by using the code given in the library itself: "Functions must have an explicit list of parameters "

Comment: `var vCard = VCard();
  vCard.firstName = profile.name!;
  vCard.organization = profile.website;
  vCard.photo.attachFromUrl(imgPath, 'PNG');
  vCard.workPhone = profile.phoneNo;
  vCard.birthday = dob;
  vCard.jobTitle = profile.profileName;
  vCard.url = profile.website;
  vCard.email = profile.email;`

Here profile is the object of my custom Class.
And I Passed that to QRCode like:
  `QrImage(
     data: vCard.getFormattedString(),
     size: 320,
     gapless: false,
     ),`

Answer (score 0):

For generating the QR Code use [qr_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter).

For saving the generaed QR Code use following functions:

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
final path = await _localPath;
return File('$path/contact.vcf');
}

Future<File> _createFile(String data) async {
final file = await _localFile;
return file.writeAsString(data);
}
```

There for you need [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider).

And for sharing the QR Code use [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share)

```
IconButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          var _vcf = await _createFile(_data);
          await Share.shareFiles(
            [_vcf.path],
            subject: 'vCardName',
            text: 'vCard',
          );
        },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
      )
```